# Java pass by reference int

Tags: java

here is my code

```
public class Scale {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 4;
        int y = 3;
        int faktor = 2;

        skaliere(x,y,faktor);

        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }

    public static void skaliere(int x, int y, int faktor){

        // ?

    }
}
```

I want to change the scale the x and y by faktor, not using  a return value. Just by the skaliere method.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to change the scale the x and y by faktor, not using a return value. Just by the skaliere method.

Note that Java is not *pass by reference*, it's always *pass by value*.

Without any hack, simply you can't because they are primitives. If they are *mutable objects*, yes you can change their state.

That hack would be making them static and assigning values inside that method.

Comment: Note that the hack would also make it impossible to call that method recursively or multithreadedly.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this with an object that wraps the two values.  This is because the object reference is passed to the method.  If you pass a primitive which are immutable, they will never be changed on the return, it would only change a copy in the method.  Using an object, you can pass the containing values and it would be the ones referenced by the main method when retrieved.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point
    Point p = new Point(0, 0);
    p.x = 4;
    p.y = 3;
    int faktor = 2;
    skaliere(p,faktor);

    System.out.println(p.x + " " + p.y);
}

public static void skaliere(Point p, int factor){
    p.x *= factor;
    p.y *= factor;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always make your own `MutableInteger` class

```
class MutableInteger{
        private int value;

        public MutableInteger(int v){
            this.value = v;
        }

        public int get(){
            return value;
        }

        public void set(int newValue){
            this.value = newValue;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Integer.toString(value);
        }


    }
```

Then use it in your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MutableInteger x = new MutableInteger(4);
    MutableInteger y = new MutableInteger(3);
        int faktor = 2;

        skaliere(x,y,faktor);

        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }

    public static void skaliere(MutableInteger x, MutableInteger y, int faktor){

        x.set(x.get() *faktor);
        y.set(x.get() *faktor);
    }
```

Since you are making your own class, you can even move the `skaliere` method into your MutableInteger

```
 class MutableInteger{
    ...
        public void skaliere(int faktor){
            this.value *=faktor;
        }
  }
```

which makes your code look like this:

```
 public static void skaliere(MutableInteger x, MutableInteger y, int faktor){

      x.skaliere(faktor);
      y.skaliere(faktor);
    }
```

You don't even need the static method anymore